# How to make POST request with Spring-android without key-value parametrs

Tags: java, android, spring, post

I can do this with android functions:

I have post parametrs like JsonString:

```
    String parametrs = "{\"object\": \"parametr\"};
```

And then im setting connection, creating String entity and makingRequest:

```
    String url = "http://lalala.com/json/";
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity se = null;

    ...
        se = new StringEntity(parametrs, "UTF-8");
    ...
    request.setEntity(se);      

    String jsonString = null;

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();  
    ...
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);  

    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
 ......
```

How can i do this thing with spring?

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
String parametrs = "{\"object\": \"parametr\"}";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.put(new URI("http://lalala.com/json/"), parametrs);
```

It is the same result on server (I test it with Google App Engine + Spring MVC).
But maybe you should think about a Jackson libery, so you would be able to send Objects =)

I use:

- jackson-annotations-2.4.1.jar
- jackson-core-2.4.1.jar
- jackson-databind-2.4.1.1.jar
- spring-android-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar

Jackson downloadable  [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.core%22)

So you would be able to send it like:

```
restTemplate.put(new URI(http://lalala.com/json/), new Example(1L, "test");
```

By the way: the above code doesn't use the params, it uses the body to send the information.

Hope I was able to help you.
Let's try again and again and ...